# Has anyone tried to find the wavelength to the Corona virus cell?

Tags: acoustics, spectroscopy, wavelength, resonance, medical-physics

I have seen websites and videos that show how cancer cells can be destroyed using sound resonance oscillation. So has anyone heard of anyone who is in the field of sound resonance trying to capture the wavelength of the Corona virus so we can create a Sonogram machine to use against this virus pandemic?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. While your question pertains to physics concepts, we prefer questions that actually ask about understanding those concepts. Therefore, I have voted to close your question as "engineering" because it asks about applying scientific knowledge to solve a specific problem.

Comment: Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope estimation of the frequency?

Comment: I've deleted a number of obsolete and/or irrelevant comments. Please keep in mind that comments should be used to suggest improvements to the question or to request clarification.

Answer (score 3):

It's a nice idea. Sadly it won't work but there is still some interesting physics involved.

As a general rule resonance is only an efficient way to transfer energy to an object if that object has a [high Q factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor). A high Q factor means the energy supplied builds up and increases the amplitude of the oscillation, and this may get large enough to damage the object. This is the (alleged) mechanism for the shattering of wine glasses by overenthusiastic sopranos. Wine glasses have a high Q and you can tell this by the way they ring for a while when you tap them. As a contrast, potatoes have a low Q and do not ring when you tap them. So our sopranos would have a hard time shattering a potato.

The problem with using ultrasound to kill cells or viruses is that in general they are squishy low Q objects like potatoes, not high Q objects like wine glasses, and they do not store the energy of the sound efficiently enough for the amplitude of oscillation to build up to destructive levels. So the technique simply won't work.

[Ultrasound is used to kill tumours](https://www.cancerresearchuk.org/about-cancer/cancer-in-general/treatment/other/high-intensity-focused-ultrasound-hifu), but this does not work by resonance - the energy in the sound simply heats the cancer tissue and kills it. It is used for tumours because the sound can be focused onto the tumour where it causes local heating. This would not work for viral infections since the virus is distributed throughout the body not concentrated in one area onto which the sound can be targeted.

Even if viruses were brittle like glass it would still be hard to make them resonate enough to be damaged when they are in a fluid like water. There are two reasons for this.

Firstly water is much denser and much more viscous than air so it efficiently damps the vibrations of any objects moving in it. For example if you tap a glass underwater it will not ring as it does in air. So even objects that have a high Q factor in air will have a drastically lower Q factor in water. This applies to viruses in humans since as far as sound waves are concerned human tissue is little different from water.

Secondly sound waves are a compression wave and they propagate by alternately compressing and expanding the water. The amount the water compresses and stretches is determined by the bulk modulus and this is relatively high. That means the amplitude of the wave is small unless the energy is very high, and consequently the mechanical deformation of objects in the water by the wave is small. This makes it hard to deform the virus enough to damage it.

Answer (score 0):

Coronavirus does not have cells. For that matter - no viruses have cells since they are sub-cellular organisms that hijack others' cells to reproduce. (Note the difference with bacteria, which are cellular organisms.)

A viral particle typically consists of a protein coat, the viral genome hidden inside, and some auxiliary proteins to launch replication of the virus. Once it penetrates a cell, the coat opens and the viral genome enters the cell. There are many different ways how viruses can replicate within a cell - the science of *molecular virology* deals with it. [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-life-cycle-of-SARS-CoV-and-MERS-CoV-in-host-cells-SARS-CoV-and-MERS-CoV-enter-target_fig1_330374659) is a visualization for the coronavirus family, that is probably too confusing for those not familiar with the subject... but it is hard to make it simpler than that.

On the other hand, the ultrasound techniques in question interact not with the individual cells, but with the tissues formed from these cells, which have different properties in respect to sound propagation as compared to the healthy tissues. Indeed, there are no such techniques capable of detecting single cancer cells - rather one detects whole tumors. This is why the use of these methods against coronavirus is unlikely.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing everyone with the term cell. I should state that resonance will go to the molecular level of destruction. I refer to the virus cell as that is the final structure of the molecular construct.

Comment: It has a bearing on the question. If a virus is not a cell, then a cure that kills cells in cancer may not be the best approach.

Comment: question answered. If I can these sites that work on cancer with ultrasound frequency https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKh2XFmsUx4 and one site that states they are looking at bacteria killing resonance as well. Here is one such site:http://novobiotronics.com/ResearchProjects.html. Let me know if the site or the video are fake or not.

Comment: One can destroy cancer or bacteria using ultrasound waves, but it is done on the level of a tissue or a bacterial colony rather than on a single cell level. Cells have size of the order of a few micrometers - too small to target them with sound waves one by one.

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference between cancer and a virus infection.

A virus invades a cell and uses it to produce more virus. These go on to invade more cells. Many viruses reproduce so much that the cell bursts. To many dead cells kills the patient, or at least makes him sick.

Cancer is a problem where the patient's cells malfunction. They reproduce uncontrollably. The mass of growing cells is called a tumor. A tumor can kill the patient. One "cure" for cancer is to kill just the out of control cells.

If you applied this approach to a virus, you would have to kill more or less all the cells in the patient.

Comment: It is my believe that at the subatomic level, a frequency can be found as the fingerprint for every living cell. So I am asking is that true from anyone out here in the physics world. If that is true, then a whole new area of medicine can be created. I believe the video and website I found answers my believe but I can't them to respond to my questions so I'm looking at the physics community for answers.